# Change font color using the jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I'm creating a web app with jquery mobile, and i'm trying to change the color of the background pages, but somethings is wrong.

It's creating this strange effect:

[image]

I'm changing the color to white, because i'm using a background-color.. if i dont make changes, the words will appears like this:

[image]

Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using text-shadow property, try with this css code:

```
tag{
 text-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: i will accept your reply in 5 minutes :D

Comment: Perfect ! i'm glad to hear that